# Should all, none, or some overridden methods call Super?

Tags: object-oriented

When designing a class, how do you decide when *all* overridden methods should call `super` or when *none* of the overridden methods should call `super`? Also, is it considered bad practice if your code logic requires a mixture of supered and non-supered methods like the Javascript example below?

```
ChildClass = new Class.create(ParentClass,
{
   /**
    * @Override
    */
   initialize: function($super) {
      $super();
      this.foo = 99;
   },

   /**
    * @Override
    */
   methodOne: function($super) {
      $super();
      this.foo++;  
   },


   /**
    * @Override
    */
   methodTwo: function($super) {
      this.foo--;  
   }
});
```

After delving into the iPhone and Android SDKs, I noticed that `super` must be called on *every* overridden method, or else the program will crash because something wouldn't get initialized. When deriving from a template/delegate, *none* of the methods are supered (obviously). So what exactly are these "je ne sais quoi" qualities that determine whether a *all*, *none*, or *some* overriden methods should call super?

Comment: The super must be called on every overriden method or else the program will crash (referring to iPhone and Android SDK and also in context of JavaScript) is not general object oriented design, it's technical. I override without calling 'super' just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Martin Fowler, [this is anti-pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html).

I think it's a good read, if you don't already know that article.

> Call Super is a minor smell (or anti-pattern if you like) that crops up from time to time in OO frameworks. Its symptoms are pretty easy to spot. You are inheriting from a super-class in order to plug into some framework. The documentation says something like "to do your own thing, just subclass the process method. However it's important to remember to start your method with a call to the super-class". An example might be something like this.
>
> ```
> public class EventHandler ...
>   public void handle (BankingEvent e) {
>     housekeeping(e);
>   }
> public class TransferEventHandler extends EventHandler...
>   public void handle(BankingEvent e) {
>     super.handle(e);
>     initiateTransfer(e);
>   }
> ```
>
> Whenever you have to remember to do something every time, that's a [sign of a bad API](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/IEEE_Software_JulAug_2004.pdf). Instead the API should remember the housekeeping call for you. The usual way to do this is to make the handle method a Template Method, like this.
>
> ```
> public class EventHandler ...
>   public void handle (BankingEvent e) {
>     housekeeping(e);
>     doHandle(e);
>   }
>   protected void doHandle(BankingEvent e) {
>   }
> public class TransferEventHandler extends EventHandler ...
>   protected void doHandle(BankingEvent e) {
>     initiateTransfer(e);
>   }
> ```
>
> Here the super-class defines the public method and provides a separate method (often referred to as a hook method) for the subclass to override. The subclass writer now doesn't have to worry his ugly head about calls to super. Furthermore the super-class writer is free to add calls after the subclass method if she wishes...

Comment: Well, your new `doHandle()` is a *far* more restricted customization-point: You decided that omitting the call to `housekeeping` is not allowed, passing other argument to `housekeeping` is not allowed, executing other code before `housekeeping` is not allowed: The only thing still allowed is adding something *after* `housekeeping`. If that's the only useful thing, fine. If it isn't, you have to redesign, and things easily get *really* messy.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not you should call super depends on whether you are trying to add to the existing functionality of the method or to replace it. That is totally dependent on what the method is doing and in some cases may even depend on the parameters.